# Robinson projection in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, epsg, plot

How can I apply [Robinson projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection) in a [GeoPandas plot](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/robin.html)?

```py
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot(column='pop_est')
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`cartopy`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) library to bring in the Robinson details.

More details on the [GeoPandas Docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/cartopy_convert.html).

```
import geopandas as gpd
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
robinson = ccrs.Robinson().proj4_init
world.to_crs(robinson).plot(column='pop_est')
```

[image]